# How to replace key pair of a certificate

Tags: c#, certificate

I have a X509 certificate which I received from a web service. No certificate request (PKCS10) was used when getting the certificate but a user specific transfer key was used instead. In my C# application I read the certificate from a file like this:
`X509Certificate cert = new 509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(certificatePath));`
The certificate's PrivateKey field is null but PublicKey isn't (is this normal?)

Now I would like to make this certificate use my own key pair. This far I have tried this:
`openssl rsa -out keypair.pem 2048` <- create the new public/private key pair
`openssl pkcs12 -export -out a.pfx -inkey keypair.pem -in cert.pem` <- create the certificate with the new keypair

The first command seems to work OK but the second command prints this message: `No certificate matches private key`. Is this the correct way to solve this? I need to have a private key for the certificate because the private key is needed to sign other request made in the web service. How could I replace the key pair of the certificate with my own private key?

Comment: There is no private key, because it is absent in your file, i.e. this is not .pfx file but .cer. I suggest you to create self-signed certificate for your webservice. There is nothing you can do with existing .cer file

Comment: OK, I'll try creating the self-signed certificate.

Comment: My colleague told me that I must do a certificate request and get the certificate again to be able to use my own private key. Sorry for a bit unnecessary question.